# Can I get json response without using ajax call in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can I get the JSON response without using ajax call.

***Method - 1 (I can easily get the JSON result)***

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/Controller/MyMethod",
        data: $.toJSON(),
        success: function () {
            document.location.href = "/Controller/Index";
        }
    });
```

***But I want to get the JSON result without ajax call. As given below:-***

```
$('#uploadForm').attr("action", "/Controller/MyMethod/")
```

Can I get the JSON result in jquery, I am not using ajax call for calling  ***MyMethod()***

Comment: not clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: can you show us some of your .Net code and a bit more context about what youre trying to achieve. At the moment, my initial instinct is to direct you towards aNewtsoft.Json which you can get from Nuget, but without more information I could be sending you in the wrong direction.

Comment: yes you can, you can append the json directly on the page as a js variable

Comment: I have update the question for clarity..

Comment: Create a model property, then assign it from action method of your controller. Then use that property in your view.